# SQL-like statements in pandas?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to run the following SQL statement (obviously in Python code) in pandas, but am getting nowhere:

```
select year, contraction, indiv_count, total_words from dataframe
    where contraction in ("i'm","we're","we've","it's","they're")
```

Where `contractions` is `char`, and `year`, `indiv_count`, and `total_words` are `int`.

I'm not too familiar with pandas. How do I create a similar statement in Python?

Comment: Have you read the docs? [Comparison with SQL](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html)

Comment: Thanks. both of these answers are what I needed. I just didn't find them in search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend reading the docs listed in Anton's comment if you haven't already, but it lacks documentation for the `.isin()` method which is what you will need to replicate the SQL `in`.

```
df[df['contraction'].isin(["i'm","we're","we've","it's","they're"])]
```

The columns selection can then be obtained using `.loc[]` or whatever you're favorite method for that is (there are many).

Comment: That's exactly the solution I came up with from the documentation. Thanks.